# How can I remove my bios password?

Tags: laptop, bios

I need to install windows 10 from bios with usb stick, i tried many ways to crack bios password but it didn't work.
My computer: Casper Nirvana NB

note: I have a laptop

Comment: You have downvoted my answer that included the advice to contact the Casper Support team, which raises doubts about your ownership of this computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can google for a some kind of master password, but there's a way that works for 100% which is a bit harder to do on a laptop:

Theres a small battery on the mainboard that makes it possible to store all settings and configurations.
Remove it and wait some seconds, so it completely resets the mainboard settings (including the set up password). Then insert the battery again and you can Install Windows.